# Get the image url using key after decoding json array into normal php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I really have no idea how to do this. Can't figure it out. Any help would be great, please and thank you.

JSON code (it is stored in 'images' column in tblproducts table in the database)

```
{
"200x200":"http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/p/s/u/lenovo-k6-power-k33a42-200x200-imaezt6hypjzhdug.jpeg",
"400x400":"http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/p/s/u/lenovo-k6-power-k33a42-400x400-imaezt6hypjzhdug.jpeg",
"800x800":"http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/p/s/u/lenovo-k6-power-k33a42-800x800-imaezt6hypjzhdug.jpeg",
"unknown":"http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/p/s/u/lenovo-k6-power-k33a42-original-imaezt6hypjzhdug.jpeg"
}
```

I need to decode that json array into normal php array using `json_decode` function⁠⁠ and get the image url using key, fetch each of the image and display it in different tag.

```
<?php 
      $category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
      $result = mysql_query("select * from tblproducts where category_id = '$category_id");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
          $json = $row['images'];
          $image = var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
      ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
          <img src="<?php echo $image[1] ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
          <img src="<?php echo $image[2] ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Unclear, what you are asking ?

Comment: i need to decode the json array into normal php array using json_decode function⁠⁠ and get the image url using key. The main thing i need to fetch each of the image and display it in different tag. Its not working the way i need. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your php code to iterate over the fetched array, and remove `var_dump()` from your code as

```
<?php 
    $category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("select * from tblproducts where category_id = '$category_id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $json = $row['images'];
        $image = json_decode($json, true);
        foreach($image as $key =>$val){
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $val ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
   <?php }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
$image = var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

do

```
foreach($image as $key =>$val)
{?>
  <img src="<?php echo $val ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
<?php }
```

you need to iterate using `foreach` on each value

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

echo $obj['unknown'];
// http://img.fkcdn.com/image/mobile/p/s/u/lenovo-k6-power-k33a42-original-imaezt6hypjzhdug.jpeg
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5e920d72a3600ec8e34390dae700ac90f897ab1)